# I changed solr.in.sh file and restarted solr. but solr core went down

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr5

I am running my solr in cloud mode. I have 3 shards and 6 cores. each shard has 2 nodes. I needed to change JMX configuration hence I change solr.in.sh file and restarted solr on one of the solr machines. Looks like core associated with that machine went down. Can anyone please help.

Comment: I am using solr 5.4.1 in cloud mode with external zookeeper. I increased JVM SOLR_HEAP = '2g'. and enabled jmx. ENABLE_REMOTE_JMX_OPTS = 'true' and set the port value for RMI_PORT.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we were calling optimize call on solr quite frequently.

SolrCloud does not require index optimization as deleted documents are removed from Index segment files as the segments are merged.

SolrCloud's replication performance and its overall performance suffer dramatically when indices are optimized. Replication performance suffers because optimized indices have to be copied in their entirety, while unoptimized indices can be copied segment by segment. Overall performance suffers because optimization requires lots of CPU time and
IO time.

There should be no need to explicitly optimize indices.

If you are calling optimization quite frequently that might have slowed down your replication.

Comment: Also if you are running your solr in cloud mode make sure you you make changes to one replica at a time. Make sure it caches up with leader and then make change to next replica.